# convnet suddenly drop accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision

I was trying to train an emotion recognition model on the fer2013 dataset using the architecture proposed in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.05371.pdf)

The paper uses different dataset than mine so I did some modifications on on the stride and filter size.
After a couple hours of training, accuracy on both training and test set suddenly drops.[image: here is when the drop happen]

After that the accuracy just stay around 0.1-0.2 for both set, never improve anymore.
Does anybody know about this phenomenon?

Answer (score 2):

In any neural network training, if both accuracies i.e. training and validation improves at first and then starts decreasing, it is a sign that your network is failing to converge. More appropriately, your optimizer has started overshooting.

One most likely reason for this could be high learning rate. Reduce your learning rate and then check your example again. Also, in your linked paper, (at least in first glimpse), I couldn't see learning rate mentioned. Since your data is different from the paper's, same learning rate might not work as well.

Comment: The learning rate is what I thought to be the issue as well but I already used a pretty small learning rate (0.005) so It's hard to believe the optimizer will overshoot anything

Comment: Can you reduce it further and check?

Comment: I will try and see how its going, it will take a long time to get to that point so I was pretty reluctant to do it

Comment: Did you check, as first step, the performance on transfer learning from the proposed model over your dataset?